# Javascript: Storing a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hello I am not very good at javascript, and I am trying to save the value returned from

```
(Math.random() + '') * 1000000000000000000 + '?'
```

Inside a cookie using: document.cookie

So far I have this:

```
document.cookie="rand="(Math.random() + '') * 1000000000000000000 + '?'";path=/";
```

But it is just storing (Math.random() + '') * 1000000000000000000 + '?' as a string and not actually using it to compute a value, can some please explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var TheNumber = Math.random() * 1000000000000000000;

document.cookie = "rand=" + TheNumber.toString() + '?";path=/"';
```

Comment: I think it has to do with the ending. What's '?";path=/"'; for?? Noticed I changed the way you had the " and ' in there.

Comment: the question mark was because it forms part of a url somewhere else, but I can concatenate that in later, let me try without.

Comment: If you want to set 2 cookies then set 2 cookies: you need 2 statements.

Comment: I'd do document.cookie = "rand=" + TheNumber.toString(); and then if you need to add a value for something else, just add another document.cookie="whatever" statement right after. It'll be easier to maintain later: one command per statement is good practice.

Comment: Works beautifully thank you I will accept you answer asap. While your here, if you wouldn't mind. In the following code, where it generates the random number I would like to insert the value from the cookie and concatenate the question mark on the end. How would I do that? 
`var AdServer = {
  tile: 1,
 mock: false,
  ord:  (Math.random() + "") * 1000000000000000000 + '?',`

Comment: var TheNumber = (Math.random() * 1000000000000000000).toString() + "?";     Why do you write (Math.random() + "")??? ; no need for the  + ""

Comment: @MD: there's no messaging functionality on the site, just ask your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value of your math operation to a variable and then append that into your cookie string. Be sure to use the + to concatenate it. It seems you forgot it in your example.